# Android Studio Google ML Kit TextRecognizer: are there options to improve detection quality?

Tags: android, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I have written an Android application to analyze screenshots and extract data for further analysis.

Unfortunately it happens that characters get extracted twice.
For example the value 15.134.567 is detected as one line with elements 15.134 and 4.567.
When I combine the line to get the full value -> 151344567 which is one digit too long, because 4 has been detected twice.
This happens very random, so maybe 1 out of 30 values is detected wrong.

Is there any improvement possible?
e.g. predefined scan area, adjust limits, change to greyscale image, set expected data format ##.###.### ?

Thanks a for for your help!

[example image for OCR][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbtSx.jpg

Comment: I'm running the default code from google ML Kit:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android

Comment: Have you tried using Tess-Two library for Android? It is very easy to integrate and if you are only trying to read digits in a single line there should not be any problem!